# virtualenv python - using Pydev with Eclipse neon

Tags: python, eclipse, virtualenv, pydev

So I've just hit the wall and seemingly not making any progress on this issue.
I just created a virtualenv called test by using Python 3.5's venv. I can activate it from terminal window and deactivate it. So far so good. I also see that the python interpreter in test/bin is actually a symbolic link to my original python 3.5 installation under /Users/LV/anaconda/bin/python3.5

My question is I want to work on a project and keep its site-package folder separate from other projects. I use Eclipse and Pydev. So I created a sample project and when I try to change the python interpreter to test/bin/python, the fact that it is a symbolic link, it gives me an error that I can't use the same interpreter twice. Fine, I don't really care about the interpreter but the problem is all packages under site-packages under my original python installation are still available to me. Where do I tell it that I need to start fresh with external packages and not necessarily use the existing ones? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Inside of PyDev, you can just point directly to the Python that's inside the virtual env.

i.e.: say you have

```
/venv
/venv/env1/bin/python
/venv/env2/bin/python2
```

Pointing to `/venv/env1/bin/python` and `/venv/env2/bin/python2` should do the trick...

Now, for it to not get the original site packages, that venv also shouldn't have access to it (I don't remember the command line for it, but from what I remember you can specify whether or not it should have its own site-packages).

i.e.: if you run from the command line:

`import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))`

it should have only the paths you expect it to have (with or without the original site-packages).

Comment: Well, that's exactly what i tried and it is not working..so i originally have /Users/LV/anaconda/bin/python3.5 and I tried to create another virtual env called test. Within test/bin/, python is a symlink to /Users/LV/anaconda/bin/python3.5. Pydev is considering as the same interpreter and won't let me create the same one again, which is fine by me. I don't necessarily need a new interpreter but how do I keep the site-packages of my virtual env different than my original site-packages?

Comment: How exactly are you creating the virtualenv (i.e.: command line)?

Comment: yes, i am using command line to create it. The command i am running is python -m venv test

Comment: I must say I just tested you exact steps and couldn't reproduce your issue (i.e.: when I created an interpreter with python3.5 -m venv test and added that interpreter to PyDev it didn't reuse the original site-packages, only the 'lib' packages, which is expected -- also, it allowed adding the new interpreter without resolving the symlink)... So, my guess is that you're using an old PyDev version (which resolved those symlinks and can't be used with virtualenvs). So, please upgrade PyDev (you can see the current version at the preferences > PyDev).